# Extending plot window beyond x-axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot` I have a graph whose x-axis labels extend beyond the plot window in RStudio even if I try to export the picture and no matter how wide I make the picture. Below is my current solution using `limits` in `scale_x_continuous`. Is it possible to have the picture extend so that I can capture my last x-axis label (i.e., 25021643) but without having the line segment extend?

[image]

Code to reproduce above:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- 
  ggplot(NULL) + 
  xlab("x-axis") + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.integer(seq(0,25021643,(25021643/4))), limits=c(0,26021643),labels = as.integer(seq(0,25021643,(25021643/4))), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, (nrow(chr5)+1)), expand = c(0,0))  +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = -1, xend = 0, yend = -0.9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 25021643, y = -1, xend = 25021643, yend = -0.9)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(size=1), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=20))
p
```

Comment: A very unelegant way to do it would be to just end the x axis at the previous value and then include 25021643 using `geom_text`

Comment: Please include a reproducible example of your code.

Comment: without a reproducible example it's hard, but maybe add a break...scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,6255410, 12510821, 18766232, 25021643))

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the code and it already is using breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `plot.margin=unit(c(0,20,0,0),"mm")` seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

`plot.margin = margin(r = 20, unit = "mm")`

Just another way of doing the same thing, but avoiding writing the values for all sides of the plot: 't' is top, 'r' is right, 'l' is left, and 'b' is bottom. You can write all or any sides you wish separated by a comma:

`plot.margin = margin(r = 20, l = 30, b = 15, t = 40, unit = "mm")`

or, if you wish to use standard units ('pt'):

`plot.margin = margin(r = 20)`